# tf.contrib.learn yields error message "module has no attribute 'learn' "

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Here is a snippet of my code taken directly from the tf.contrib.learn tutorial on tensorflow.org:

```
# Load Data Sets
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename = IRIS_TRAINING,
    target_dtype = np.int,
    features_dtype = np.float32)
```

Here is the error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-7122d1244c55> in <module>()
     11 
     12 # Load Data Sets
---> 13 training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
     14     filename = IRIS_TRAINING,
     15     target_dtype = np.int,

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'learn'
```

Clearly the module has the attribute learn since tensorflow has a section on learning tf.contrib.learn. What am I doing wrong? All guidance is appreciated.

Comment: what's your TF version? tf-learn hasn't been there always, if you have an old version you might want to update.

Comment: I have version 0.7.1. I am aware that there is a later version but whenever I try to update I get the following error:          
                          
File "...\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 93, in <module>
    __gen_path__ = iter(sys.modules["win32com.gen_py"].__path__).next()
AttributeError: 'list_iterator' object has no attribute 'next'

Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: That sounds like a py2 vs py3 issue (executing py2 code with py3), but that is a separate question.

Comment: I moved to a different machine with updated python and it worked - thank you for pointing this out.